# Unable to get value from redis using webflux

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-webflux

Currently I am storing some value in redis.

When I try to get the value I am getting `MonoNext`.

This is the code

```
redisOps.opsForValue().set(sId + "_" + cId + "_" + suffix, true);

Mono<String> data =  redisOps.opsForValue().get(sId + "_" + cId + "_" + suffix);
```

I am expecting it to be of `Mono<String>`.

Is there something wrong here?